# How to find eigen vector matrix when eigen values are repeated??

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

if we find the eigen values for Matrix  A  $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -2\\1 & 2 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$
I got 2 and 1 with 2 repeat twice 
And I Got eigen vectors $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
for 2 and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ for 1 
 I want to find P such that A= $P^{-1}$.D.P
where D is diagonal matrix
I know that columns in P are eigen vectors corresponding to eigen value in D. if my D= $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
which vector coming first since there are two vectors for two How to determine first vector situation like that(not only for this problem)?

If P=$$\begin {pmatrix} 1 &0&-2 \\\ 0&1&1 \\\ -1 &0&1\end{pmatrix}$$i got answer but when P=$$\begin {pmatrix} 0&1&-2 \\\ 1&0&1 \\\ 0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$i didn’t get back A correctly how to determine which vector coming first since (1 0 -1),(0 1 0) both are coming from eigen value 2[image: Problem is which vector should take first as a column vector]

Comment: Put the eigenvectors in the same order you put the eigenvalues.

Comment: If P=[(1 0 -1)|(0 1 0)|(-2 1 1)] i got answer but when P=[(0 1 0)| (1 0 -1)| (-2 1 1)]i didn’t get answer how to determine which vector coming first since (1 0 -1),(0 1 0) both are coming from eigen value 2

Comment: Vectors are COLUMNS

Comment: It shouldn't matter which vector comes first. You should get the same answer either way. Please, recheck all your calculations (or at least post the details here, so we can peruse them without having to reconstruct them ourselves).

Comment: But I think you want $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is correct

For each vector:

$Av = \lambda v$

So for the set:

$AP = PD$

$PDP^{-1} = A$

or $D = P^{-1}AP$

You should have:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&-2\\1&0&1\\0&-1&1\end {bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2\\&2\\&&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\-1&0&-2\\-1&0&-1\end {bmatrix} = A$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-2\\0&1&1\\-1&0&1\end {bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2\\&2\\&&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&-2\\1&1&1\\-1&0&-1\end {bmatrix} = A$

Comment: I want to find P but 2nd P shows in image doesn’t give A correctly

Comment: Sure it does, you are multiplying the matrices incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you!!! my problem solved.